# Merging Two Queries in Access with Common Keys and Different Totals

Tags: microsoft-access

I have two queries that I have set up that have all the same fields except the totals. I am wanting the result to have the all the same fields as the original queries, but I want to have 2 total columns (Supplies purchased and supplies used) i.e. If all the codes were the same for each query except amount then the first record in the new query would have the amount purchased and used side by side.

I tried to link them with a join and I ended up getting duplicate values and other abnormalities which made the totals very high. I also tried a union of all the fields except for the sum columns. I then did a query off of that and the original 2 queries doing a join that only took records matching the union query except for amount, but the results were still funny.

I'm not sure where I went wrong. These were the fields for the original queries.

**Query 1**

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
| Year | Month | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 | Sum of Supplies Purchased |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
| 2003 |    01 |   123 |   123 |   123 |   123 |                    10,000 |
| 2003 |    02 |   124 |   123 |   123 |   123 |                    20,000 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
```

**Query 2**

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------------+
| Year | Month | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 | Sum of Supplies Used |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------------+
| 2003 |    01 |   123 |   123 |   123 |   123 |                5,000 |
| 2003 |    02 |   124 |   123 |   123 |   123 |                6,000 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Can you include the expected result for your sample data?

Comment: You say “These were the fields for the original queries.”  I don’t understand what you mean.  What does your *data* (i.e., your table) look like?  What *queries* are you using?  What results are you getting?  And, as Lee Mac asked, what result do you want? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.